Determine the k largest positive integer that can select k positive integers from {1, 2, ... ,2017} ...
Determine the k largest positive integer that can select k positive integers from {1, 2, ... ,2017} such that among the selected numbers, no two numbers are coprime, and no any two numbers whose quotient is an integer.(They may be divisible by several numbers together, but they are not divisible by each other, like 6 and 8).
i have some ideas i don't know if it works.
The numbers must have the same prime divisor but they are not divisible by each other. I think the common divisor is 2 (to get the largest k).
And k will be approximately the average value of the given population. I think that choosing prime numbers aj less than or equal to 1008 and numbers 2×aj will satisfy the problem conditions. But I have no way to calculate how many prime numbers are less than 1008.
Another idea is that we can split the original set into two sets of even numbers and odd numbers. And continue to split them in half and rely on the average principle to solve it. I'm confused here

As a way to get started, I suggest doing the same problem for a cap smaller than $2017$.  Note:  your claim that "the numbers must have the same prime divisor" isn't obviously true.  ${6, 10,15}$ has the property that no two elements are relatively prime, yet no single prime divides all  three.  Perhaps your claim is true for a maximal collection, but that requires a proof.

If it helps:  Wolfram Alpha can easily compute the number of primes less than a modest threshold.  In your case, we see that there are $168$ primes less than $1008$.

One possibility is all the even numbers greater than $2017/2$.

@GerryMyerson That turns out to yield the correct maximum, but there are multiple optimal solutions.
